# Python requests | Разное содержимое в файлах при одинаковом коде

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу одинаковый код на сервере и на компуктере, в файлах получается разное содержимое. Как так и что делать?

Comment: Там же английским по белому написано, как так и что делать. Какое слово непонятно?

Comment: В html ответе слева написана причина, читайте текст с **Access**

Answer (score 1):

[PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) не позволяет обращаться к сторонним сервисам.

Точнее позволяет, но только к [ограниченному списку](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/):

> Free accounts' internet access goes via a proxy "whitelist". Here is
>   the list of sites currently allowed:
>
> https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/
>
> We operate this to prevent malicious users from using our site to hack
>   into and spam other websites. Paid-for accounts don't have this
>   limitation, because we can connect them to real people. Spammers and
>   criminals prefer to be anonymous, so we figure they're unlikely to
>   sign up for paid accounts here.